# "This type of file can harm your computer mac no keep option" - No "Keep" option? macOS HS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, download, macos-high-sierra

I have encountered the usual Chrome "feature" of displaying "this type of file can harm your computer mac no keep option" when trying to download a file from a filehosting website.

However, when the warning appears there is only ever a "discard" button and not one to "keep" the file as I have seen when using Windows...

[image]

Can anybody suggest anything?

Comment: I've just started getting the same thing (on macOS). Was working fine until a couple of days ago. The only option I've found so far is to have Chrome ask where you want to save each time.

Comment: I have the same issue. This is not actually a bug. A terrible design choice. I think we should wait for them to notice this.

Comment: How is this not a bug?  Asking "do you want to keep ... anyway?" and then not offering an option to do so seems very odd.

Comment: *This is fixed in the Canary channel (Chrome 67)*. Also, in the future, post questions about general software on **[Super User](https://superuser.com/)**; rather than on StackOverflow, as they are off topic here. Read more in the **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: Sorry about that @Toastrackenigma - I've only recently discovered the other offshoots of Stackoverflow, so I will bare that in mind for the future.

Comment: Apparently, this issue is fixed in the new beta so should be gone soon. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=823108 Until then, the workaround is go to chrome://downloads (Window -> Downloads) or Command+Shift+J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@DickKennedy Helped resolve my woes with a workaround for this by going to Chrome settings and enabling the option "Ask where to save each file before downloading" in the downloads section.

[image]

This isn't a fix, but it certainly gets the job done!

Answer (score 14):

Going to the downloads list (Command+Shift+J) shows you the Keep option.

[image: Downlaods list]

Comment: That is one solution I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - super annoying issue. Luckily a small work-around that works is going to Window -> Downloads and clicking on "Keep" there.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would downvote this - it's the only answer here that actually provides a temporary solution to the problem, without completely disabling the warning.